# how can i cancel the default action if user set my action as default in my app?

Tags: android, default

how can i cancel the default action if user set my action as default in my app?

Comment: @CaseyB i mean i want ti know the API to cancel the default action,like home action to be canceled.

Answer (score 4):

Easy. Go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications.

Find the app that was set to default (For example, Google Maps or Youtube or ADWLauncher) and click it.

Near the bottom of the list you'll see Launch By Default. Click the Clear default button.

Comment: hi, i want to know the Android code to do this, rather than operatoin to do this by system.

Comment: resolved, use PackageManager.clearPackagePreferredActivities(String packageName) can handle it.